# How do I make my opening reportorie stronger, specifically my Grand Prix Attack against high level competition?

Tags: opening, analysis, learning, theory

I saw the DVD Killer Grand Prix Attack from GM Gawain Jones. This helped a lot. However, I have some trouble with some concepts against 2 ...e6 lines. According to the DVD the second plan of the Grand Prix Attack is to play Bb5 and capture the Nc6 to give Black double c pawns then attack the double pawns in a positional way. However, I sometimes heard you have to transition to Closed Sicilian or Open. Here is an example were I'm unsure.

1. e4 c5
2. Nc3 e6
3. f4 Nc6
4. Nf3 d6
5. Bb5 Nge7
6. o-o g6
7. d3

Would it better to play Bb5 earlier to go for the double pawn plan or 5. Bb5 here is better such as this game was played? Would 7. d4 be better than 7. d3?

What are further resources to study the Grand Prix Attack seriously?

Answer (score 2):

As resource:

Please check [Lawrence Trent's](https://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/trent_the_modern_grand_prix_attack) analysis from White's perspective and [Andrew Martin's](http://en.chessbase.com/post/andrew-martin-refuting-the-grand-prix-attack)'s from Black's perspective.

About line:

I don't find it correct to say anything about this line without studying state-of-the-art. So, you better check experts analyses for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A strong player is going to know how to get a good position against an opening like this that is considering weak. Theory and computers suggest your position favors Black.  There have been 29 master level games played from this position with Black winning the majority of them.

That said, after Bg7, White should play Qe1.  Below is a sample game.  12. Qe4 was the losing move but the best move was the embarrassing retreat 12.Qe1.

[Event "Ch England"]
[Site "England"]
[Date "2015.3.22"]
[Round "8"]
[White "Dean Michael (ENG)"]
[Black "Levy Christopher A (ENG)"]
[Result "0-1"]
[Eco "B23"]

1.e4 c5 2.Nc3 Nc6 3.f4 e6 4.Nf3 d6 5.Bb5 Nge7 6.O-O g6 7.d3 Bg7
8.Qe1 h6 9.Qh4 Bd7 10.f5 exf5 11.exf5 g5 12.Qe4 Bxf5 13.Bxc6+
bxc6 14.Qa4 O-O 15.Be3 Be6 16.Rae1 Qd7 17.Ne2 Nf5 18.Bd2 d5 19.d4
cxd4 20.Nexd4 Nxd4 21.Nxd4 c5 22.Qxd7 Bxd7 23.Nf5 Bxf5 24.Rxf5
Rad8 25.Ba5 Rd7 26.c4 Bd4+ 27.Kf1 dxc4 28.Bc3 Rb8 29.Rd1 Rdb7
30.Rd5 Bxc3 31.bxc3 Rb1 32.Kf2 Rxd1 33.Rxd1 Rb2+ 34.Kf3 Rc2 35.Rd8+
Kg7 36.Rc8 Rxc3+ 37.Ke4 Rc2 38.Kf3 Rxa2 39.Rxc5 Ra3+ 40.Ke2 c3
41.Kd3 Ra2 42.Rxc3 Rxg2 43.h3 Rg3+ 44.Kc4 0-1